# Streaming audio. How does 10 seconds of audio are loaded in 2 seconds?

Tags: objective-c, stream, audio-streaming, avplayer

Dunno if that the right place to post the question.

However out of curiosity, how does 10 seconds are loaded in 2 seconds? I could have understand if an audio being loaded to the fileserver and the client is loading it afterwards. However lifestream that comes from RTSP I have got two answers,

- It's either loads played content
- Or the internet lifestream is behind real stream...

Anyway I would like to hear your aswers and guidance on this topic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's the second option. If you would stream audio in "real time" without any delay, you would have serious problems when the connection is lost or data is delayed, for example, for 100ms. Than the user wouldn't hear anything for 100ms, which would be pretty annoying. This especially happens with mobile connections, which have much higher error rates and while you move have a hard time to keep a stable connection.

Usually the acutal playback is delayed and the next seconds are buffered. When the connection is down and comes back in the buffered time frame, than the user doesn't notice that the connection was lost. In you example the connection can be lost for up to 8 seconds without any problems.

Comment: But what do you think... RTSP stands for real-time streaming protocol

Comment: So my question would be... why not to call it delayed-time streaming protocol... what's so reallictic about this streaming?

Comment: @JackieChan, It's about as real time as it gets.  Also, the buffer is configurable.